# Normalizing the values of first data set based on the value of mean/S.e in the second data set

Tags: r

I have two data sets. The first data set includes the observations and the second data set includes the values of mean and s.d. I am looking for a short way (loop function)to make normalize *standard normal* each row of Frequency in the first data set based on the value of mean and variance from the second data set. I mean, I want to add four columns to the first data set,the first column would be the normal values of Frequency based on the Mean/S.e from the first row of the second data set, the second column is the normal values of Frequency based on Mean/S.e from the second row of the second Dataset and so on.

```
Subject <- seq(1, 13, 1)
Frequency <- c(7,79,509,2240,2341,623,476,228,168,140,114,64,22)
A<-data.frame(Subject,Frequency)
Mean<-c(11,12,13,14)
S.e<-c(1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4)
B<-data.frame(Mean,S.e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this accomplishes what you're looking for:

```
colA<-ncol(A)
for(i in 1:nrow(B)){
  A[,colA+i] <- (A[,2]-B[i,1])/B[i,2]
  names(A)[colA+i] <- paste("Prob",i,sep = "")
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks. Since I have lots of columns in the original data set, how I can modify your code to change the column names to Prob1, Prob2, Prob3, Prob4?

Comment: I've made an edit to the code that should change the names. Could you accept my answer if you like it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
for (i in 1:nrow(B)) A <- cbind(A,(A[,2]-rep(B[i,1],nrow(A)))/rep(B[i,2],nrow(A)))
names(A) <- c("Subject","Frequency","Norm1","Norm2","Norm3","Norm4")
```